# ValueError: time data '67:01' does not match format '%M:%S'

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a TEXT column called Used which contains the duration in minutes:seconds for phone calls. I would like to convert this to a a duration format. The problem is some of the minutes are greater than 59 so giving an error:

```
time data '67:01' does not match format '%M:%S'
```

The code to convert this is:

```
df.Used.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%M:%S'))
```

Is there a simple way to convert this to a decimal minutes format? Something like 67.01666 for 67:01?

Comment: You want the column in datetime  format? datetime should always have year/day/month , etc . If you are storing duration it seems that `timedelta` would be more suiting for this.

Comment: How would I be able to implement this?

Comment: how did you create your dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation for the **[`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)** object you can have values for minutes only between to `[0-60)` range:

> The year, month and day arguments are required. tzinfo may be None, or an instance of a tzinfo subclass. The remaining arguments may be ints or longs, in the following ranges:
>
> 1. 0 <= hour < 24
> 2. 0 <= minute < 60
> 3. 0 <= second < 60
> 4. 0 <= microsecond < 1000000

So, there is no possible way to get rid of that error. if you want to convert this to a decimal minutes format, which I'm guessing is just a `decimal` you'll need to do it manually like so:

```
# Split the string, join it and cast it to float
df.Used.apply(lambda x : float(".".join(x.split(":"))))
```

Which outputs:

```
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame([['87:01'],['911:11']],columns=['Used'])

In [6]: df.Used.apply(lambda x : float(".".join(x.split(":"))))
Out[6]: 
0     87.01
1    911.11
Name: Used, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following which seems similar to some of the answers above. Using split I made two dataframes, one for minutes and another for seconds which I converted to float and then combined them to form a decimal column in the original dataframe.

```
test_df = home_df.Used.str.split(':')
minutes_df = test_df.str[0]
seconds_df = test_df.str[1]
minutes_df = minutes_df.astype(float)
seconds_df = seconds_df.astype(float)
decmin_df = minutes_df + seconds_df / 60.
home_df['Duration'] = decmin_df
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing duration , I would suggest that the correct way for storing durations would be `Timedelta` , not `datetime` (since a datetime always requires an year/month/day , etc. basically `datetime` is used to denote exact dates/times).

For that an quick/easy way would be to split the string based on `:` and then pass them separately to `minutes` and `seconds` argument of `datetime.timedelta` . Example -

```
df.Used.apply(lambda x: datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(x.split(':')[0]), seconds=int(x.split(':')[1])))
```

Demo -

```
In [15]: import pandas as pd

In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame([['67:01'],['11:11'],['59:59'],['09:08']],columns=['Used'])

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
    Used
0  67:01
1  11:11
2  59:59
3  09:08

In [18]: import datetime

In [19]: df.Used.apply(lambda x: datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(x.split(':')[0]), seconds=int(x.split(':')[1])))
Out[19]:
0   01:07:01
1   00:11:11
2   00:59:59
3   00:09:08
Name: Used, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

If you want it as float, you can also do it with a simple change -

```
df.Used.apply(lambda x: float(x.split(':')[0]) + float(x.split(':')[1])/60)
```